# DLL function in python not working when imported from different folder

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have a C++ function exported in a DLL file that I'm trying to use in python. The function takes as input an array of 7 ints, and returns a single int. I created the following code in python:

```
import ctypes
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
handle = ctypes.CDLL(dir_path + "/evaluator.dll")


def get_rank(int_list):
    IntArray7 = ctypes.c_int * 7
    input_array = IntArray7(*int_list)
    value = handle.My_Function(input_array)
    return value
```

When calling the function I get some strange results.
When calling the function from the same folder, the function works as intended. However when I try to call it from a parent folder (or any other folder for that matter), the function always returns 0 for some reason, even with the exact same input. The DLL file is in the same folder as the above function.
I'm not sure if I'm messing something up with relative imports or if it's something else. All code still runs, it just returns inconsistent results...

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  I created a DLL with your function signature, put the DLL in a subdirectory along with your code above.  From the parent directory, I added the subdirectory to `sys.path` so `import <abovecode>` would work, and called `get_rank` and it worked.  Please provide the *exact* steps and C and Python code to reproduce your issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for your response. I actually got it to work already in part because of your answer. I went over my C++ code again so that I could post it here for reproducible and I found an (apparant) mistake in there. I use another file in my C++ code which I imported using a relative path. Changing this to its full path fixed the inconsistencies in my python code. Thanks